# Solving QGIS error Python Plugin is Broken?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I tried following the steps to build a python plugin for QGIS. (step 3 is where I am stuck at)

1) I used the Plugin Builder plugin to build the initial set of files. I call my plugin "PointWithinRadius". After using the plugin builder I have the files: **init**.py, pointwithinradius.py, resources.qrc, etc..(the usual files)

2) Next I ran pyrcc4.exe and was able to get resource.py from resource.qrc

3) Tried running pyuic4.bat as follows: (but get the errors as seen below)

```
![C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Copiapo\bin>pyuic4.bat -d -o "C:\Users\stalmaki\.qg
is\python\plugins\PointRadius\ui_pointradius.py" -x "C:\Users\stalmaki\.qgis\pyt
hon\plugins\PointRadius\ui_pointradius.ui"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\port_v2\invoke.py", line 44, in
invoke
    exit_status = driver.invoke()
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\driver.py", line 69, in invoke
    self._generate()
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\driver.py", line 103, in _genera
te
    self._opts.pyqt3_wrapper, self._opts.from_imports)
AttributeError: Values instance has no attribute 'from_imports'][1]
```

I am unable to figure out the reason for this and searching for this error didn't give me much success either.

Finally when I try opening my plugin in QGIS, I get the following (see attached screenshot jpeg)

I want to build a sort of hello world plugin at first but these errors are not allowing me to get out of the starting blocks. Any help on solving would be great.

My development environment:
Windows 7 32 bit
QGIS 1.6.0
Python 2.5
Qt 4.7

[image]

Comment: This is more of a development question than a GIS one, so you might want to ask it on the qgis-dev mailing list.

Comment: Have you tried using an OSGeo4W install?

Comment: @MerseyViking. I was afraid of that. I will stick to GIS specific questions from next time.

Comment: @underdark
I installed QGIS as an independent binary as I already had Python 2.5 installed. Does using OSGeo4W take care of some of the other linking and PATH issues that are known to crop up? Thanks

Comment: @underdark
Thanks!...using OSGeo4W worked like a charm. I guess because I installed pyQt4 separately, there may have been some errors not finding the path, etc.

Comment: @nerazzurri_4; make sure you mark your question as answered.

Comment: @nerazzurri_4; instead of changing the title to *Solved* you could use the "Answer Your Question" option which is indeed recommended.

Comment: I faced the same error - try installing python 2.7 - it worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using OSGeo4W should take care of the PATH issues on Windows systems and keep all packages compatible.